# Is using Classname.method name instead of super() the only solution if we want to enforce call to the parent class method?

Tags: python

Is there any way to ensure that when an instance of B or instance of any subclass of B is created, then the test method from A must be invoked?

Current code is as follows:

```
class A:
    def test(self):
        print(" test of A called ")
class B(A):
    def test(self):
        print(" test of B called ")
        super().test()
class C(A):
    def test(self):
        print(" test of C called ")
        #super().test()
class E(B):
    def test(self):
        print(" test of E called ")
        super().test()
class D(B,C):
    pass

obj1=B()
obj1.test()
print('xxxxxx')
obj3=E()
obj3.test()
print('xxxxxx')
obj2=D()
obj2.test()
```

Output:

```
B
A
xxxxxx
E
B
A
xxxxxx
B
C
```

How to ensure A output in the last case also. Is changing the class B's test method to A.test() instead of super().test() the only solution?

And this means that the 3rd output will no longer be B, C and will now be B, A. Is there any way to retain B, C, A?

Comment: If you are going to use `super`, you need to use it in *all* classes. If both `B` and `C` use `super.test`, then `obj2.test` will (eventually) invoke `A.test`.

Answer (score 1):

Your failure to use `super` in `C.test` breaks the chain of calls that would eventually lead to `A.test` being called. `super` supports *cooperative* inheritance, which means all classes need to cooperate by using `super` consistently.

```
class A:
    def test(self):
        print(" test of A called ")


class B(A):
    def test(self):
        print(" test of B called ")
        super().test()


class C(A):
    def test(self):
        print(" test of C called ")
        super().test()


class E(B):
    def test(self):
        print(" test of E called ")
        super().test()


class D(B,C):
    pass
```

Now when you invoke `obj2.test()`, you'll start with `B.test` (since `D.test` is not defined). The call to `super` in `B.test` leads to `C.test` being called, and the call in `C.test` will lead to `A.test` being called.

Answer (score 0):

what do you think of my next solution:

```
class A:
    def test(self):
        print(" test of A called ")


class B(A):
    def test(self):
        print(" test of B called ")
        super().test()


class C(A):
    def test(self):
        print(" test of C called ")
        super().test()


class E(B):
    def test(self):
        print(" test of E called ")
        super().test()


class D(B,C):
    pass


obj1=B()
obj1.test()
print('xxxxxx')
obj3=E()
obj3.test()
print('xxxxxx')
obj2=D()
obj2.test()
```

Output:

```
 test of B called 
 test of A called 
xxxxxx
 test of E called 
 test of B called 
 test of A called 
xxxxxx
 test of B called 
 test of A called 
 test of C called
```